# Having difficuly using a switch statement with classess and for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, class, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a photo-view display similar to pintrest except there is a preference `checkbox` where you can choose the types of images you see.

The problem I'm having is that some of these images fall under multiple catergories, for example there might be a driving shot in the city, so I want that particular image to show if either the city `checkbox` or drivng images `checkbox` is clicked.

Currently I have it so say for example, City `checkbox` is clicked and becomes `unchecked`, then all images with the city `class` get a class of `displayNone` which does the obvious. But I want to make it so if it also has another `class` that is currently `checked`then it doesnt get the `class` of displayNone, only when all the classes of that particular image are `unchecked` is when that image gets the `class` of displayNone.

I know that the switch statement would be ideal for this scenario but I can't seem to figure out exactly how I'd implement it.

```
  HTML

  <!--PREFERENCE CHECKBOX-->
                      <div class = "preferanceCheckbox">
                          <form class ="formBox">
                              <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" class = "cBDrivingShot">
                              Driving Shots <br>
                              </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" class = "cBCyberPunkShot">
                              Cyberpunk <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class = "cBcityRelated">
                              city related <br>
                           </form>
                       </div>


      <div class ="photoSectionAlignment pintrestView imgZ displayNone">

 <!-- CYBERPUNK SHOTS -->
          <img src="cyberPunkOne.jpg" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgDrivingShot displayNone">                                     

          <img src="cyberPunkTwo.jpg" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgCity displayNone">

          <img src="cyberPunkTwo.jpg" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgtext displayNone">

 <!-- DRIVING SHOTS -->
         <img src="drivingShotOne" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCity displayNone">

         <img src="drivingShotTwo" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCity displayNone">

         <img src="drivingShotThree" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCyberPunk displayNone">

 <!-- CITY SHOTS -->
         <img src="cityShotOne" class = "pImg pImgCity displayNone">
    </div>


 CSS

 img {
 width: 200px;
 }

 .displayNone {
 display: none;
 }


  JAVASCRIPT  

  //GLOBAL VARIABLES
  //....................................................................

  var pintrestView = document.querySelector(".pintrestView");

  var dnPintrest = pintrestView.classList.contains("displayNone");


  // GLOBAL PREFERANCES CODE
  //..................................................................
  var drivingCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBDrivingShot");
  var cyberPunkCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBCyberPunkShot");
  var cityCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBcityRelated");

  //PREFERANCES CODE
  //..................................................................

  // pintrest class variables
  var pImgDrivingShot = document.querySelectorAll(".pImgDrivingShot");
  var pImgCyberPunk = document.querySelectorAll(".pImgCyberPunk");
  var pImgCity = document.querySelectorAll(".pImgCity");

  //DRIVING SHOT FUNCTIONALITY
  drivingCheckBox.addEventListener("click",drivingShotImgFunctionPintrest);

 function drivingShotImgFunctionPintrest(){

     if (drivingCheckBox.checked === true){
         for (var i = 0; i < pImgDrivingShot.length; i++){
             if (pImgDrivingShot[i].classList.contains("displayNone")) {
                 pImgDrivingShot[i].classList.remove("displayNone");
             }
         }
     }else{
         if (drivingCheckBox.checked === false) {
             for (var i = 0; i < pImgDrivingShot.length; i++){ 
                 if (pImgDrivingShot[i].classList.contains("displayNone") === false) {
                     pImgDrivingShot[i].classList.add("displayNone");
                 }

             }
         }  
     }
 }

  //CYBERPUNK FUNCTIONALITY
  cyberPunkCheckBox.addEventListener("click",cyberPunkImgFunctionPintrest);

  function cyberPunkImgFunctionPintrest(){

     if (cyberPunkCheckBox.checked === true){
         for (var i = 0; i < pImgCyberPunk.length; i++){
             if (pImgCyberPunk[i].classList.contains("displayNone")) {
                 pImgCyberPunk[i].classList.remove("displayNone");
             }
         }
     }else{
         if (cyberPunkCheckBox.checked === false) {
             for (var i = 0; i < pImgCyberPunk.length; i++){ 
                 if (pImgCyberPunk[i].classList.contains("displayNone") === false) {
                     pImgCyberPunk[i].classList.add("displayNone");
                 }

             }
         }  
     }
 }

  //CITY FUNCTIONALITY
  cityCheckBox.addEventListener("click",cityImgFunctionPintrest);

  function cityImgFunctionPintrest(){

      if (cityCheckBox.checked === true){
          for (var i = 0; i < pImgCity.length; i++){
              if (pImgCity[i].classList.contains("displayNone")) {
                  pImgCity[i].classList.remove("displayNone");
              }
          }
      }else{
          if (cityCheckBox.checked === false) {
              for (var i = 0; i < pImgCity.length; i++){ 
                  if (pImgCity[i].classList.contains("displayNone") === false) {
                      pImgCity[i].classList.add("displayNone");
                  }

              }
          } 
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another take using CSS rules and just one event listener:

```html
<!-- Place this inside your <head> -->
<style id="preferences"></style>
<!--PREFERENCE CHECKBOX-->
<div class = "preferanceCheckbox">
  <form class ="formBox">
      <input id="drive" type="checkbox" value=".pImgDrivingShot">
      <label for="drive">Driving Shots</label><br>
      <input id="cyber" type="checkbox" value=".pImgCyberPunk">
      <label for="cyber">Cyberpunk</label><br>
      <input id="city" type="checkbox" value=".pImgCity">
      <label for="city">City Related</label>
  </form>
</div>

<div class ="photoSectionAlignment pintrestView imgZ">
  <!-- CYBERPUNK SHOTS -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/100/50" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgDrivingShot displayNone">     <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1022/100/50" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgCity displayNone">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1023/100/50" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgtext displayNone">
  <!-- DRIVING SHOTS -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1041/100/50" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCity displayNone">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/50" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCity displayNone">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1019/100/50" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCyberPunk displayNone">
  <!-- CITY SHOTS -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1080/100/50" class = "pImg pImgCity displayNone">
</div>
```

```css
 .displayNone {
  display: none;
 }
```

```js
const selected = {};
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   if ( e.target.type === "checkbox" ){
     const cssClass = e.target.value;
     if (e.target.checked){
       selected[cssClass] = true;
     } else {
       delete selected[cssClass];
     };
     const cssRules = `${Object.keys(selected).join(",")}{ display: block !important; }`;
     document.querySelector("style#preferences").textContent = cssRules;
   }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/povzeQQ?editors=1111)

The code is much more easy to **extend**: you just add a pair of label/input:checkbox (2 lines) in the form for each new class of images.

```html
      <input id="summer" type="checkbox" value=".pImgSummer">
      <label for="summer">Summer Related</label>
```

Comment: This works great via your codepen example but for whatever reason it doesn't work when I copy it into the code for my project, I've read over everything 3 times as well :( it's defientely the exact same formula as what you've written. 
any idea why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: yeah I ended up getting it @KostaX , for the querySelector choosing the form box I had to use form.formbox which worked perfectly. Only problem I have now is I actually have a few different viewing modes and want to apply this same logic to each of the modes but it only works for the pintrest view.. idk maybe I'll make another post and let you know when I do?

Comment: Sure. Just make sure you try and solve it yourself, and post it on S.O. only when you feel stuck. @JoshMcIntosh

Answer (score 1):

very first used change event rather than click for the checkbox.

JS

```
var pintrestView = document.querySelector(".pintrestView");

var dnPintrest = pintrestView.classList.contains("displayNone");


// GLOBAL PREFERANCES CODE
//..................................................................
var drivingCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBDrivingShot");
var cyberPunkCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBCyberPunkShot");
var cityCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBcityRelated");

//PREFERANCES CODE
//..................................................................

// pintrest class variables
var pImgDrivingShot = document.querySelectorAll(".pImgDrivingShot");
var pImgCyberPunk = document.querySelectorAll(".pImgCyberPunk");
var pImgCity = document.querySelectorAll(".pImgCity");

//DRIVING SHOT FUNCTIONALITY
drivingCheckBox.addEventListener("change", drivingShotImgFunctionPintrest);

function drivingShotImgFunctionPintrest() {
    for (var i = 0; i < pImgDrivingShot.length; i++) {
        if (this.checked) {
            pImgDrivingShot[i].classList.remove('displayNone')

        } else {
            pImgDrivingShot[i].classList.add('displayNone');

        }
    }
}

//CYBERPUNK FUNCTIONALITY
cyberPunkCheckBox.addEventListener("change", cyberPunkImgFunctionPintrest);

function cyberPunkImgFunctionPintrest() {
    for (var i = 0; i < pImgCyberPunk.length; i++) {
        if (this.checked) {
            pImgCyberPunk[i].classList.remove("displayNone")


        } else {
            pImgCyberPunk[i].classList.add("displayNone");
        }
    }

}

//CITY FUNCTIONALITY
cityCheckBox.addEventListener("change", cityImgFunctionPintrest);

function cityImgFunctionPintrest() {


    for (var i = 0; i < pImgCity.length; i++) {
        if (!this.checked) {
            pImgCity[i].classList.remove("displayNone");
        } else {
            pImgCity[i].classList.add("displayNone");
        }
    }

}
```

HTML: remove display none for your parent div

```
               <div class = "preferanceCheckbox">
                          <form class ="formBox">
                              <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" class = "cBDrivingShot">
                              Driving Shots <br>
                              </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" class = "cBCyberPunkShot">
                              Cyberpunk <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class = "cBcityRelated">
                              city related <br>
                           </form>
                       </div>


      <div class ="photoSectionAlignment pintrestView imgZ">

 <!-- CYBERPUNK SHOTS -->
          <img src="cyberPunkOne.jpg" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgDrivingShot displayNone">                                     

          <img src="cyberPunkTwo.jpg" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgCity displayNone">

          <img src="cyberPunkTwo.jpg" class = "pImgCyberPunk pImgtext displayNone">

 <!-- DRIVING SHOTS -->
         <img src="drivingShotOne" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCity displayNone">

         <img src="drivingShotTwo" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCity displayNone">

         <img src="drivingShotThree" class = "pImgDrivingShot pImgCyberPunk displayNone">

 <!-- CITY SHOTS -->
         <img src="cityShotOne" class = "pImg pImgCity displayNone">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to reduce the numbers of loops that are in the Javascript code.  I think that you really want the same logic, but there are some variables in the styles.  If you can identify the variables, then the looping can all be handled in one place.  Here's how I approached the problem:

```
// GLOBAL PREFERENCES CODE
//..................................................................
var drivingCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBDrivingShot");
var cyberPunkCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBCyberPunkShot");
var cityCheckBox = document.querySelector(".cBcityRelated");

drivingCheckBox.addEventListener("click", updateFromCheckbox);
cyberPunkCheckBox.addEventListener("click", updateFromCheckbox);
cityCheckBox.addEventListener("click", updateFromCheckbox);
function updateFromCheckbox(evt) {
    console.log('In updateFromCheckbox');
    var selector = "";  // The class that corresponds to the current checkbox
    var otherSelectors = [];    // Array of classes that correspond to the OTHER checkboxes
    var otherCheckboxes = [];   // The boolean settings of the OTHER checkboxes
    if (evt.currentTarget === drivingCheckBox) {
        selector = "pImgDrivingShot";
        otherSelectors = ["pImgCyberPunk", "pImgCity"];
        otherCheckboxes = [cyberPunkCheckBox.checked, cityCheckBox.checked];
    } else if (evt.currentTarget === cyberPunkCheckBox) {
        selector = "pImgCyberPunk";
        otherSelectors = ["pImgDrivingShot", "pImgCity"];
        otherCheckboxes = [drivingCheckBox.checked, cityCheckBox.checked];
    } else if (evt.currentTarget === cityCheckBox) {
        selector = "pImgCity";
        otherSelectors = ["pImgDrivingShot", "pImgCyberPunk"];
        otherCheckboxes = [drivingCheckBox.checked, cyberPunkCheckBox.checked];
    }

    // Safety check
    if (otherSelectors.length != otherCheckboxes.length) {
        console.log("otherSelectors AND otherCheckboxes ARE PARALLEL ARRAYS AND SHOULD BE THE SAME LENGTH!");
    }

    var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var image = images[i];
        var isDisplayed = false;
        if (image.classList.contains(selector) && evt.currentTarget.checked) {
            isDisplayed = true;
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < otherSelectors.length; j++) {
                var otherSelector = otherSelectors[j];
                var otherCheckboxIsChecked = otherCheckboxes[j];
                if (image.classList.contains(otherSelector) && otherCheckboxIsChecked) {
                    isDisplayed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isDisplayed) {
            image.classList.remove("displayNone");
        } else {
            image.classList.add("displayNone");
        }
        console.log('Got one ', image.src, 'isDisplayed = ', isDisplayed, 'classList = ', image.classList);
    }
}
```